# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed the camelcase package in python using pip. But when I import camelcase and run the code, I see this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelcase'

For the sake of providing more information, the file where I am writing the code is in a different location.

This is my code:

```
import camelcase
c = CamelCase()
txt = "hello world"
print(c.hump(txt))
```

Comment: Have you installed camelcase? If you're using a virtual environment, are you using the one in which you installed it? You can check what you've installed by running `pip freeze` on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your import try the following:

```
from camelcase import CamelCase
c = CamelCase()
txt = "hello world"
print(c.hump(txt))
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```